# set sleep after the execution of every single keyword in Robot Framework

Tags: testing, robotframework

I have several UI test cases where the code looks like

Click       …

Sleep     1

Click       …

Sleep     1
.
.
etc

I want reduce the redundancy of code so that I write only the keywords and it automatically sleep one second after the execution of each, is there a way in RObotFramework?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface

Answer (score 0):

You can set a delay for every test step you have by using "Set Selenium Speed"
Then you don't need to put sleep after every test step.

http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Set%20Selenium%20Speed